# How to install and run Recovery Disk Assistant on Mac OSX from terminal single user mode

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

Need some advise on installing and run the Recovery Disk Assistant on Mac OSX Lion Mac mini (mid.2011), that is bad on discrete graphics card. 
I need to move from OSX Lion to a Linux distro, for it is the only possible (and free of cost) solution to make this mac usable only in Intel HD graphics card.

The Recovery Disk Assistant is needed to have a system back up in case there is a case to move back to Mac OSX.
Googling for installation instructions found [this](http://macappstore.org/recovery-disk-assistant/) page. Need to mention that system is bootable only in single user mode.

Has anyone used those terminal commands with success? Thank all in advance for your answers.